# Как сделать такой BottomSheet с отступами и закругленными углами?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не получается сделать чтобы были отступы.

Это Floating BottomSheet. Я увидел его в этом приложении https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.material.components. Он снизу появляется.

Comment: это Dialog, а не BottomSheet

Comment: скорее BottomSheetDialog